# How to finish this quirky basement window

Tags: trim-carpentry, egress

I have a basement egress window by a concrete knee wall, but based on window height and the height of the concrete knee wall the bottom of my rough-in window is a few inches below the concrete.

I know how to insulate the concrete and was planning to use 2” rigid foam, but with little clearance around this window (especially for the window control lever that opens the window itself) I’m at a loss on how to insulate this area and trim out this window.

Do you have any ideas? Do I need to remove more of the concrete knee wall?

[image: window]

Comment: You would need to cut the knee wall back at least 12" x the "few inches below the concrete", ideally all the way to the inside vertical face of the knee wall (maybe even creating a step or two) since you need ease of access. Only an engineer can tell you if this is possible as we have no idea why the site conditions warranted this construction.

Comment: What are the dimensions of this window's opening (the clear dimensions of the opening that you climb through, not the window frame's dimensions)? And how high is that flat concrete surface above the finished floor? Is this window in a sleeping room? Are there any other windows in the basement, and if so, then what are their opening dimensions? Differentiating the height dimension from the width dimension is important.

Answer (score 1):

The IRC calls a window like that an "emergency escape and rescue opening," assuming it meets the requirements. The stairs up from that space and your front door are probably the egress. The relevant section of the code is [IRC R310](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310). Consider replacing the window with a shorter one.

Step one: Figure out if this window is necessary as an emergency escape to meet code. Small utility basements are the one exception that can get away with no emergency escape, otherwise every basement requires an emergency escape. Every sleeping room requires an escape, where a single bedroom and the whole basement can share a single escape. If this particular window is a redundant escape, then a shorter one will work. In this scenario, you want to make sure that the alternative escape meets all of the code's prescriptions. There's a 44" maximum window sill height above finished floor, for instance.

Step two: If you don't have a redundant escape, then measure the window's net opening dimensions and compare them to the code's minimum height, width, and area (24", 18", and 5.7 ft<sup>2</sup> = 821 in<sup>2</sup>, respectively). If there's enough excess between your window's net height and area versus the code's requirements, then a shorter window will work.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: I don’t know the size requirements for an egress window, but is there any chance a smaller window would meet code?

Instead of trying to “finish the quirky window” can you replace it with something shorter that doesn’t extend below the concrete?

Option 2: It doesn’t *look* like you can move the existing window up, but can you?

Option 3: Install a bumpout or box bay window. (Google those terms) Basically, build a box that mounts on the exterior wall and move the window outward. Insulate as required.